# Send e-mail from Python through Zoho

Tags: python, imap, zoho

I'm trying to send an e-mail from Zoho, but: sometimes I receive emails, sometimes not, and it happens also with other persons.

But in `mail.zoho.com` all emails exists in SENT E-MAILS, but people sometimes did not receive, and it is not a Spam problem.

```
def sendMailTo(subject='', msgHTML='', to='', no_reply=False, mail_type=None):
    try:
        j = json.loads(msgHTML)
        msgHTML = ""
        for k in j.keys():
            msgHTML += str(k) + ": " + str(j[k])
            msgHTML += "\n"
    except ValueError:
        pass

     #Create the root message and fill in the from, to, and subject headers
    msg = MIMEMultipart('related')
    msg2 = MIMEText(msgHTML, 'html', 'UTF-8') #Content-Type: text/html; charset="us-ascii"
    msg.attach(msg2)

    # This example assumes the image is in the current directory
    import os
    os.chdir(os.path.dirname(__file__))
    #print(os.getcwd())
    fp = open('./utils/images/logo.png', 'rb')
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    # Define the image's ID as referenced above
    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<logo>')
    msg.attach(msgImage)
    fp = open('./utils/images/facebook.png', 'rb')
    msgImage = MIMEImage(fp.read())
    fp.close()
    # Define the image's ID as referenced above
    msgImage.add_header('Content-ID', '<facebook>')
    msg.attach(msgImage)

    recipients = [to]
    TO = ", ".join(recipients)
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['To'] = TO

    if no_reply:
        FROM = "no-reply@xxxxx.com"
        msg['From'] = FROM
        # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
        # envelope header.
        s = smtplib.SMTP_SSL('smtp.zoho.com', 465)
        # s.set_debuglevel(1)
        # s.starttls()
        s.ehlo()
        s.login(FROM, 'yoyoyoyoyoyo')
        s.sendmail(FROM, recipients, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
    else:
        FROM = "xxxxxxxxx@gmail.com"
        msg['From'] = FROM
        # Send the message via our own SMTP server, but don't include the
        # envelope header.
        s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
        #s.set_debuglevel(1)
        #s.ehlo()
        s.starttls()
        s.login(FROM, 'yoyoyoyoyoyo')
        s.sendmail(FROM, recipients, msg.as_string())
        s.quit()
```

Comment: If you have successfully connected to the server, and you can see the mails in the server-side sent items folder but the recipients have not received the mails, how do you know it they aren't being marked as spam?  The fact that you can send from gmail doesn't mean that mails from zoho aren't being marked as spam somewhere between zoho and the recipient.

Comment: I think that the problem is that I need a TLS certificate.